# How to disable SSL certificate validation in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl

I'm new to this above topic.I just wanna know how to disable ssl in asp.net website using c#.I got something in this link...
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm

Comment: Your current question title makes it sound like you want a way to ignore certificate validation errors, however, the link you provide makes it look like you want to disable SSL 3.0.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yeah,Kenneth Ito I want to use tls instead of ssl.Is it possible?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/637207/on-iis-how-do-i-patch-the-ssl-3-0-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable it easily (if you can, probably you do, it isn't worth it).

Instead you can put any certificate to Trusted Root Authorities so it will be always valid.

See [Installing a Certificate as a Trusted Root CA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)